# Is there a way to map an entity to a temporary table in Android Room?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I need to create a temporary table to insert hierarchical data in an Android Kotlin app database that uses Room. Is there a way to link an entity class to a temporary table ? Thanks in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

From testing it does not appear that TEMPORARY tables are supported/usable within Room but that instead you would have to use psuedo temporary tables *(non-temporary that would be cleared not necessarily defined as @Entity annotated classes)*.

Consider the following demonstration that :-

- shows the use of TEMPORARY table outside of Room using the android SQLiteDatabase class.
- shows the use, within room of a pseudo temporary table, culminating in a query that links to an @Entity annotated table.
- shows how the TEMP table does not appear to work resulting in a table not found, even though data is apparently successfully inserted.

First two @Entity annotated classes **Parent** and **Child** :-

```
@Entity
data class Parent(
    @PrimaryKey
    val parentId: Long? = null,
    val parentName: String
)
```

and :-

```
@Entity
data class Child(
    @PrimaryKey
    val childId: Long? = null,
    val parentLink: Long = -1,
    val childName: String
)
```

A single @Dao annotated abstract class **AllDao** :-

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(parent: Parent): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = IGNORE)
    abstract fun insert(child: Child): Long

    @SkipQueryVerification /* ignore the unable to resolve parentAndChild table */
    @Query("SELECT parent.* FROM parentAndChild JOIN main.parent ON parentAndChild.parentId = parent.parentId")
    abstract fun getAllFromParentAndChild(): List<Parent>
    
}
```

- Note the query that retrieves data from the non-room ***parentAndChild*** table and for simplicity extracts a List via a link (JOIN) to the Parent table.

an @Database annotated class **TheDatabase** :-

```
const val DATABASE_NAME = "the_database.db"
@Database(entities = [Parent::class, Child::class], version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getAllDao(): AllDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: TheDatabase? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): TheDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME)
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as TheDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

Finally an activity where the testing/demonstration is undertaken:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    lateinit var supdb: SupportSQLiteDatabase
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        testNonRoomTempTable() // Example of using a TEMPORARY table with SQLiteDatabase rather than Room

        /* Now with Room */
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        supdb = db.openHelper.writableDatabase
        dao = db.getAllDao()

        /* Instantiate some Parent and Child Objects
        *       Parent being an @Entity annotated class
        *       Child being an @Entity annotated class
        * */
        val p1 = Parent(10,"Parent10")
        val p2 = Parent(20,"Parent20")
        val c1 = Child(1000,p1.parentId!!,"Child1")
        val c2 = Child(2000,p2.parentId!!,"Child2")

        /* Insert the objects into the respective Room tables */
        dao.insert(p1)
        dao.insert(p2)
        dao.insert(c1)
        dao.insert(c2)

        /* Create and populate a pseudo temp table (unknown to room aka not via an @Entity annotated class)*/
        createTemptTable()
        insertTempTableRow(p1.parentId,p1.parentName, c1.childId!!,c1.childName)
        insertTempTableRow(p2.parentId,p2.parentName,c2.childId!!,c2.childName)
        logTempTable() /* write the pseudo date to the log i.e. confirm existence */

        /* Use a link to an @Entity annotated class to get some data */
        for (p: Parent in dao.getAllFromParentAndChild()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Parent is ${p.parentName}")
        }

        /* Replicate BUT using a TEMPORARY TABLE rather than a pseudo temp table */
        createTemptTable(true) // true results in TEMP keyword i.e. a TEMPORARY table
        insertTempTableRow(p1.parentId,p1.parentName, c1.childId,c1.childName)
        insertTempTableRow(p2.parentId,p2.parentName,c2.childId,c2.childName)
        logTempTable() //<<<<< fails table not found
        /* Use a link to an @Entity annotated class to get some data */
        for (p: Parent in dao.getAllFromParentAndChild()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Parent is ${p.parentName}")
        }

    }
    fun createTemptTable(useTemptable: Boolean = false) {
        var createTableSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parentAndChild (parentId INTEGER, parentName TEXT, childId INTEGER, childName TEXT)"
        if (useTemptable) {
            createTableSQL = "CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parentAndChild (parentId INTEGER, parentName TEXT, childId INTEGER, childName TEXT)"
        }
        supdb.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS parentAndChild")
        supdb.execSQL(createTableSQL)
        /*
        var csr = supdb.query("SELECT * FROM temp.sqlite_master")
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr)
        csr = supdb.query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master")
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr)
        csr.close()
        */
    }

    fun insertTempTableRow(parentId: Long, parentName: String, childId: Long, childName: String) {
        val cv = ContentValues()
        cv.put("parentId",parentId)
        cv.put("parentName",parentName)
        cv.put("childId",childId)
        cv.put("childName",childName)
        Log.d("DBINFO","insert result is " +
        supdb.insert("parentAndChild",androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy.ABORT,cv))
    }

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    fun logTempTable() {
        Log.d("DBINFO","Logging ParentAndChild Table :-")
        val csr = supdb.query("SELECT * FROM parentAndChild")
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO",
                "Parent is ${csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("parentId"))} Child is ${csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("childId"))}")
        }
        Log.d("DBINFO","Completed Logging ParentAndChild Table")
    }

    fun testNonRoomTempTable() {
        val altdb = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(this.getDatabasePath("alt_database.db"),null)
        altdb.execSQL("CREATE TEMP TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parentAndChild (parentId INTEGER, parentName TEXT, childId INTEGER, childName TEXT)")
        val cv: ContentValues = ContentValues()
        cv.put("parentId",10)
        cv.put("parentName","Parent1")
        cv.put("childId",1000)
        cv.put("childName","Child1")
        altdb.insert("parentAndChild",null,cv)
        var csr = altdb.query("parentAndChild",null,null,null,null,null,null)
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr)
        csr.close()
    }
}
```

**Results when run**

The ***`testNonRoomTempTable()`*** runs as expected and produces the following dump of the Cursor into the log:-

```
2022-02-20 09:22:33.031 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@2caa87e
2022-02-20 09:22:33.032 I/System.out: 0 {
2022-02-20 09:22:33.032 I/System.out:    parentId=10
2022-02-20 09:22:33.032 I/System.out:    parentName=Parent1
2022-02-20 09:22:33.032 I/System.out:    childId=1000
2022-02-20 09:22:33.032 I/System.out:    childName=Child1
2022-02-20 09:22:33.032 I/System.out: }
2022-02-20 09:22:33.032 I/System.out: <<<<<
```

- i.e. the TEMPORARY table is accessible when not using Room

Then when using a table that is cleared (DROPPED) and created and thus effectively TEMPORARY then the log includes :-

```
2022-02-20 09:22:33.085 D/DBINFO: insert result is 1
2022-02-20 09:22:33.085 D/DBINFO: insert result is 2
2022-02-20 09:22:33.085 D/DBINFO: Logging ParentAndChild Table :-
2022-02-20 09:22:33.091 D/DBINFO: Parent is 10 Child is 1000
2022-02-20 09:22:33.091 D/DBINFO: Parent is 20 Child is 2000
2022-02-20 09:22:33.091 D/DBINFO: Completed Logging ParentAndChild Table
2022-02-20 09:22:33.093 D/DBINFO: Parent is Parent10
2022-02-20 09:22:33.094 D/DBINFO: Parent is Parent20
```

- i.e. the pseudo temporary table has hen created, populated and accessed. The last tow lines being via a link to the Parent table with Parent objects extracted.

The when trying to use an actual TEMP table :-

```
2022-02-20 09:22:33.095 D/DBINFO: insert result is 1
2022-02-20 09:22:33.096 D/DBINFO: insert result is 2
2022-02-20 09:22:33.096 D/DBINFO: Logging ParentAndChild Table :-
2022-02-20 09:22:33.098 E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: parentAndChild
```

- i.e. even though rows have been inserted, when the attempt to access the table is made, a table not found exception results.

Comment: Tx MikeT. I knew I could use that trick, unfortunately that is not exactly what I wanted, but I had to use that "dirty" solution as a wropk around